# Is it possible to specify fields of a related resource in tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

Say I have got the following model and resources:

#### models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
   field_one = fields.CharField()
   field_two = fields.CharField()
   field_three = fields.CharField()
   field_four = fields.CharField()
   readers = fields.ManyToManyField('readers.Reader')
```

#### api/resources.py

```
class PostResource(common.Resource)
    readers = fields.ToManyField('ReaderResource', 'readers')

    class Meta:
        queryset = models.Post.objects.all()


class ReaderResource(common.Resource)
    posts = fields.ToManyField('PostResource', 'post_set', full=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = models.Reader.objects.all()
```

I want to get only some specified fields from the `PostResource` when I query the `ReaderResource` but all the fields when I directly query the `PostResource`. So for example when I query the `PostResource` I want to get data similar to:

```
{
    field_one: value,
    field_two: value,
    field_three: value,
    field_four: value,
    readers: [
        # List of readers' resource uris
    ]
}
```

But when I query the `ReaderResource` I want to get only `field_one` and `field_two` from the `PostResource`, for example:

```
{
    # Other reader fields here
    posts: [{
        field_one: value,
        field_four: value,
    }]
}
```

Is there a way I can specify what fields from a related resource I want ? If there is no staright forward way to do this, then why is it so ?  Isn't this a very common use case ? Shouldn't this be built into tastypie ?

Answer (score 1):

The common way is to create one more resource, say, `SafePostResource` below `PostResource`:

```
class SafePostResource(PostResource):
    class Meta(PostResource.Meta):
        fields = ['field_one', 'field_two']


class ReaderResource(common.Resource)
    posts = fields.ToManyField('SafePostResource', 'post_set', full=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = models.Reader.objects.all()
```

without registering that resource.

Notice that creating related resource is not always easy, but Django Tastypie makes everything `easier`.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that, Also we could use `hydrate` and `dehydrate` method to add/remove field information if we are not talking a lot of fields. Was just looking for a better solution as this is a very common use case.

Comment: It seems like it's not so common. Someone on a blog had the same kind of trouble because he wanted to use 2 different Authorization types for GET and POST request, so he decided to create a "CreateUser" and a "GetUser" resource. I agree this is not elegant, but it works :)